# Tomcat 7 to 8.5 upgrade : getResourceAsStream throws NPE

Tags: java, tomcat, migration, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am new to this Dev Ops work so please forgive anything simple which I may have overlooked. I am in the middle of upgrading from Tomcat 7 to 8.5. There is not much in terms of migration manuals other then the apache website and using the [7 to 8](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Web_application_resources) then the [8 to 8.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#Web_applications). All seems ok, expect for when I start up the application and the code tries to load information using the following

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sql/");
```

or

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sql/");
```

The context path is being loaded using ROOT.xml which has a docBase pointing at the project which is in the `../tomcat/databaseLink` directory. The `WEB-INF/classes` folder is in the `../tomcat/databaseLink` directory and the `sql` folder is in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. So it all seems to be ok.

When the code is running it looks like it is looking for the `sql` folder in the `../tomcat/lib/` directory rather then the `../tomcat/databaseLink/WEB-INF/classes/sql/` directory. I have not made any changes to the default Tomcat 8 conf files. Any idea why this is happening or what I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) only finds resources, which are on the web application classpath, i.e.:

- in the folder `WEB-INF/classes` or in a JAR file inside the `WEB-INF/lib` folder,
- in the classpath of Tomcat's `Shared`, `Common`, `System` or `Bootstrap` classloaders (cf. [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)). As you noticed, by default the `Common` classloader has the directories `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` and `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` in its classpath.

The method you are looking for is [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), which searches in the application directory and `META-INF/resources` entries of all JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`. So you should call:

```java
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/sql/your_file");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was my mistake. I never added the /WEB-INF/classes/sql/ to my question but this is where the folder is (have updated my question now). And my understanding and from what you mention above the ClassLoader should work. I have read online somewhere that if it cannot find any WEB-INF/ then it defaults to tomcat/lib. Could it be that I have missed something in my web application config so its not finding the WEB-INF/ ?

Comment: Yes, `ClassLoader` looks into the `Bootstrap` classloader (JRE), `WEB-INF/classes`, `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`, `System` (usually just `$CATALINA_BASE/*.jar`), `Shared` (usually empty), `Common` classloaders in that order. It should find the file. `WEB-INF/classes` is certainly not empty, because your application is there. On the other hand you are trying to get a **directory** as stream: this won't work.

Comment: You where exactly right. I had everything setup correctly, but I was trying to get the directory as a stream. This was returning 'null'. Changed this to use 'PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver' and worked as expected